# Is it possible to develop a desktop application which integrates with the FaceBook API?

Tags: facebook, desktop-application

I would like to develop a desktop application to interact with the facebook API.

The user would be able to browse their profile and post details such as the music which they are playing or the applications which are being installed or being used.

Is this possible?

Are there any relevant tutorials?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### .NET Facebook API Client

There is a Facebook API framework for .NET applications here:

http://facebook.codeplex.com/

Building a simple desktop app in VB.NET or C#.NET is not too hard, you can download the Express version (free) here: http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/

The documentation for the framework is on the same site: http://facebook.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Home

There is also a lot of documentation for getting started with .NET and the tools are very good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, through facebook connect. There is a lot of documentation on developers.facebook.com